# how to use GTX 1660 supper GPU in tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Edit:
it worked when I reinstall tensorflow.

I have GTX 1660 supper GPU and I installed the latest version of CUDA, cuDNN and the Driver.

[image]

when I `import tensorflow as tf` I get this message.

```
2021-05-18 12:19:45.541654: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
```

but when I `print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))`
the output is empty`[]`

Comment: Can you let us know tensorflow version? Steps that you have followed to install Tensorflow, CUDA and cuDNN?

Comment: I have reinstalled tensorflow when I Installed CUDA and cuDNN then it's worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments

> I have reinstalled tensorflow when I Installed CUDA and cuDNN then
> it's worked. (paraphrased from Osama Adel)